# How to subselect a value when altering a sequence?

Tags: database, postgresql

```
ALTER SEQUENCE table_seq RESTART WITH SELECT .. FROM table
```

I'd like to reset a sequence based on a subselect. But the statement above gives a syntaxerror on `select`.

Why might I be missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think this can only be done when using the `setval()` function:

```
select setval('table_seq', (select ...));
```

Note that the `select` statement *must* be enclosed in parentheses.